# Htaccess rule doesnt work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have got this rule.. which I put as my first rule

```
RewriteRule ^categories_compare/$ index.php?app_table_comparison=3 [L]
```

This is the url that I type:

```
http://apps.com/categories_compare
```

The problem is that it doesnt do the redirect.. why is that?

This is part of my htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^news2/([^/\.]+).(html)$ index.php?news_url_two=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/([^/\.]+).(html)$ index.php?news_url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^categories_compare/?$ index.php?app_table_comparison=3 [L]
```

I want the last rule to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is: `^news3/$`, so it wants a trailing `/` at the end but you're only going to `news3`. Try changing your rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^news3/?$ index.php?app_table_comparison=3 [L]
```

The `/?` means the slash is optional.

Comment: nah... it really doesnt make a difference

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd Do you have `RewriteEngine On`?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule categories_compare http://fuckedapps.com/index.php?app_table_comparison=3 [L]
```

Okay that is the solution without any ^ or / or ^ or $.

Weird thing that it didnt work when I put ^categories_